# NSMenuItem updating title

Tags: swift, nsmenuitem

I'm able to programmatically create menu items using the following code.

`primaryMenu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "MenuTitle", action: nil, keyEquivalent: ""))`

I want to be able to update the title from this menu item. I have been able to do it very easily when I manually create the menu using Interface Building.

I don't have a way to identify the menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a reference to your `NSMenuItem` (such as in an instance variable), and set the title on it whenever you wish:

```
let myMenu = NSMenuItem(title: "MenuTitle", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")

primaryMenu.addItem(myMenu)

//somewhere else:
myMenu.title = "xyz"
```

Comment: However *somewhere else* must be in the same scope which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Added clarification

Answer (score 1):

Just create a lazy instantiated variable on the top level of the class

```
lazy var mySpecialMenuItem : NSMenuItem = {
   return NSMenuItem(title: "MenuTitle", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
}()
```

and assign the menu item to the variable

```
primaryMenu.addItem(mySpecialMenuItem)
```

Now you can change the title

```
mySpecialMenuItem.title = "Something Else"
```

The benefit of a lazy instantiated variable is it won't be initialized until it's accessed the first time and you can avoid an optional or implicit unwrapped optional.